# Dynamically create a playlist of videos in html5 and play videos sequentially

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically create a playlist of videos on html5. So I create a list of movieurls dynamically and then click on the links to play the videos. I initially used this code get the sequential video playing working: http://jsfiddle.net/Barzi/Jzs6B/9/
But if I generate the same list dynamically using javascript my links do not work. My movieurls direct to different chunks of the same video using #t. It seems that the videos are not loaded. Please suggest if anyone has a solution.

```
$(function() {
$("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": "",
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
})
$("#videoarea").attr({
    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
    "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
})
```

The way my playlist is generated is this:

```
    var playlisting = document.getElementById('playlist');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var url = "smallvideo.mp4#t=25,35";
    li.setAttribute('movieurl', url);
    li.innerHTML = somedata;
    playlisting.appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added your generation code to the jsFiddle and it seems to work fine for me.

Take a look at [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/2081/)

I have placed the url for each video in an array

```
var videos = [
  'http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4',
  'http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4',
  'http://www.ioncannon.net/examples/vp8-webm/big_buck_bunny_480p.webm'
];
```

and then looped through each item in the array

```
var playlisting = document.getElementById('playlist');
for(var i=0;i<videos.length;i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var url = videos[i]+"#t=25,35";
    li.setAttribute('movieurl', url);
    li.innerHTML = 'movie_'+i;
    playlisting.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>

<ul id="playlist">
    <li src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" moviesposter="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/screen.jpg">Happy Fit</li>
    <li src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4">Sintel</li>          
    <li src="http://html5example.net/static/video/html5_Video_VP8.webm">Resident Evil</li>      
    <li src="http://www.ioncannon.net/examples/vp8-webm/big_buck_bunny_480p.webm">Big Buck Bunny</li>
</ul>
```

And js

```
$('#playlist li').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
var curUrl =$(this).attr("src");
$('#videoarea').attr("src",curUrl)

});
});
```

Fiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/2082/